Is it correct to say “Students will *flock to you* if you are a good teacher”?
What I want to say is “If you are a good teacher, a lot of students will register for your class and study under you”.
As far as I’ve researched, “flock to somebody” means “come and visit somebody in large numbers”.
So I don’t know if the sentence Students will flock to you conveys exactly what I meant to say - A lot of students come and register for your class, not just “come and visit”

This reads like a proofreading request, which is off-topic on this site

@gotube so if I'm not sure if I'm using a phrase correctly or not, how should I ask the question here? I don't know what I should change, because I have already stated the specific part in the sentence which I'm uncertain about. I also quoted the meaning of the phrase to show how slightly different it is from the meaning I want to convey

Flock (verb) - move or go together in a crowd. I don't see anything wrong with it.

I'm guessing you've seen several definitions of the phrase from online dictionaries and other websites. You should ask by indicating what about those definitions leaves you in doubt that it would apply to students registering to study under a good teacher.

It's understandable but it's hard to tell if it's entirely suitable. It might be considered hyperbole (exaggeration). It might not be suitable for very formal contexts.

It's not visit someone in large numbers. It's go towards someone in large numbers due to popularity. Can be for any reason at all.

@Lambie so which alternative phrase should I use in this situation? What I mean is “a lot of students will come and register for my class”

It's fine the way it is. What sounds a bit weird is not the phrase. It's this: come and visit someone in large numbers.

Your example is perfectly natural and probably not all that uncommon. It's an exaggeration.

Students will flock to you if you are a good teacher.

Here's another similar one:

Students will come to your class in droves if you are a good teacher.

